# Laravel process in background

Tags: php, laravel

I need to run a specific script/application once a certain button was pressed in my `view`. Now that this process may take up some time (30 seconds and more) I'd like to inform the user of the progress and whether it is successful or not.

What I have in mind is a simple text/label and a progress bar which are 
'somehow' fed with the progression data provided by my Laravel application (the controller, to be more precise).

However, I have no clue where to start or what is best practise for a case as such.

Comment: What exactly the problem is? Have you tried something?

Comment: Take a look at `php artisan make:command` and in your controller or model, you can `Artisan::call()` the command OR use Laravel Queues.

Comment: @Hash Well, read the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the queue in laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues

For the progress part. On different parts in a job you could dispatch an event. If you want to display them in your frontend, you should use something with push notifications. Laravel also has something for that:https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting

Comment: I took a look at broadcasting and wonder, since this seems to be JS rendering the stuff on the view, how I can initiate a download then?

Comment: When the process is finished you can do a redirect with javascript or just simply show a 'download' link.